# Heroku Returns 503 on all endpoints apart from main endpoint: app works in development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

My app displays blogs, users and a login page.

The app works perfectly in development mode

The only endpoint that works in production mode is the login page right at the start.

All other GET and POST endpoints to api/blogs, api/users etc. do not work

The error in the heroku logs is H12 - request timeout with a 503 error.

Here is the app.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const config = require('./utils/config')
const express = require('express')
require('express-async-errors')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan');
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware')
const blogsRouter = require('./controllers/blogs')
const usersRouter = require('./controllers/users')
const loginRouter = require('./controllers/login')

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to MongoDB')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error connection to MongoDB:', error.message)
  })

app.use(middleware.tokenExtractor)

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static("build"))
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api/blogs', blogsRouter)
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter)
app.use('/api/login', loginRouter)

app.use(middleware.errorHandler)
app.use(middleware.unknownEndpoint)

app.use(morgan(':method :url :body'));

module.exports = app
```

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const app = require('./app')
const http = require('http')
const logger = require('./utils/logger')
const config = require('./utils/config')

const server = http.createServer(app)

const PORT = process.env.PORT
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`Server running on port ${config.PORT}`)
})
```

Controllers:

blogs:

```
const blogsRouter = require('express').Router()
const { getNextKeyDef } = require('@testing-library/user-event/dist/keyboard/getNextKeyDef')
const Blog = require('../models/blog')
const User = require('../models/user')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const getTokenFrom = request => {
  const authorization = request.get('authorization')
  if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer ')) {
    return authorization.substring(7)
  }
  return null
}
 
blogsRouter.get('/', (request, response) => {
    Blog
      .find({}).populate('user', {username: 1, name: 1})
      .then(blogs => {
        response.json(blogs)
      })
  })
  
blogsRouter.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
      const blog = await Blog.findById(request.params.id).populate('user', {username: 1, name: 1}, ('comments', {commenter: 1, comment: 1}))
      if (blog) {
        response.json(blog.toJSON())
      } else {
        response.status(404).end()
      }
  
  })


blogsRouter.post('/', async (request, response, next) => {
    const body = request.body

    const token = getTokenFrom(request)
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
    if (!decodedToken.id) {
      return response.status(401).json({ error: 'token missing or invalid' })
    }
    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
  
  if (body.title === undefined) {
    return response.status(400).json({ error: 'content missing' })
  }

  if (body.author === undefined) {
    return response.status(400).json({ error: 'content missing' })
  }


  const newblog = new Blog({
    title: body.title,
    author: body.author,
    url: body.url,
    user: user._id  })

    const savedBlog = await newblog.save()
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id)
    await user.save()

    response.json(savedBlog)

  })

  blogsRouter.post('/:id/comments', async (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    const body = request.body

  const blog = await Blog.findById(request.params.id)

  if (blog) {
    blog.comments.push(body.comment)
   const savedBlog  = await blog.save()
 response.status(200).json(savedBlog.toJSON());
  }

  } catch (exception) {
    next(exception)
  }})

blogsRouter.delete('/:id', async (request, response, next) => {
  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(request.token, process.env.SECRET)

  if (!request.token || !decodedToken.id) {
    return response.status(401).json({
      error: 'token missing or invalid'
    })
  }
  try {
    const blog = await Blog.findById(request.params.id)

    if (blog.user.toString() === decodedToken.id.toString()) {
      await blog.remove()
      response.status(204).end()
    } else {
      response.status(401).end()
    }
  } catch (exception) {
    next(exception)
  }
  })

blogsRouter.put('/:id', async (request, response, next) => {
    const body = request.body

    /* const decodedToken = jwt.verify(request.token, process.env.SECRET)

    if (!request.token || !decodedToken.id) {
      return response.status(401).json({
        error: 'token missing or invalid'
      })
    }

    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id) */
  
    const blog = {
      title: body.title,
      author: body.author,
      url: body.url,
      user: body.user._id,
      likes: body.likes
    }
  
    const savedBlog = await Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, blog, { new: true })
    response.json(savedBlog)
  })
  

  module.exports = blogsRouter
```

login:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const loginRouter = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/user')

loginRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  const { username, password } = request.body

  const user = await User.findOne({ username })
  const passwordCorrect = user === null
    ? false
    : await bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash)

  if (!(user && passwordCorrect)) {
    return response.status(401).json({
      error: 'invalid username or password'
    })
  }

  const userForToken = {
    username: user.username,
    id: user._id,
  }

  const token = jwt.sign(userForToken, process.env.SECRET)

  response
    .status(200)
    .send({ token, username: user.username, name: user.name })
})

module.exports = loginRouter
```

Users:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const usersRouter = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/user')

usersRouter.get('/', async (request, response) => {
    const users = await User.find({}).populate('blogs', {title: 1, author: 1, url: 1})
    response.json(users)
  })

usersRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  const { username, name, password } = request.body

  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username })
  if (existingUser) {
    return response.status(400).json({
      error: 'username must be unique'
    })
  }

  if (!username) {
    return response.status(400).json({
      error: 'please add a username'
    })
  }

  
  if (!password) {
    return response.status(400).json({
      error: 'please add a valid password'
    })
  }



  const saltRounds = 10
  const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)

  const user = new User({
    username,
    name,
    passwordHash,
  })

  const savedUser = await user.save()

  response.status(201).json(savedUser)
})

module.exports = usersRouter
```

Sorry for long post

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error was down to Heroku failing to connect to MongoDB.

Whitelisting 0.0.0.0/0 on MongoDB DID NOT WORK.

What worked was

Go to your app page in Heroku ---> Settings ---> Reveal Config Vars

Add the KEY as MONGODB_URI and VALUE as your MongoDB Connection String (as defined in your .env file)

The endpoints worked after applying this change.

Heroku need to emphasize the importance of this step a lot more.